# How to copy a main level to editor

Tags: geometry-dash

A lot of autos levels available online seems to be exact copies of levels, but modified.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but as far as I know, you just cannot copy them. U need to memorise them or check every one block of your level if you want to copy them. The level TOE 2(insane player-created level) is a good imitation of TOE 2 (the main level), but some rings are not in the same place. Whether to make it easier or what, I do not know but I dont think you can copy a main level.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to copy a normal level is to find copyables of it, kinda sad that you can't copy them, but at least people create copyables!

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 options. The first one is to memorize the level and make a perfect replica of the level. However, this is extremely hard, and would probably take years. However, some people have already built a replica (or hacked Geometry Dash), and have released them online. For example, to get a copy of Stereo Madness, look up Stereo Madness copyable. Then, look at the menu of a level, and look at the middle-left, there should be a copy button. If you can copy it, then you are done! However, if it requires a password, check the description and comments for the passcode! If there is none listed, then move on to the next copyable level. however, if there is no copy button at all, then move on to the next copyable level and do the same thing.

You can even copy online levels! For example, for Bloodbath, search Bloodbath copyable. However, for long level names such as The Hell Factory or The Janus Miracle, you may have to abbreviate it. Like search up THF Copyable for The Hell Factory, and TJM Copyable for The Janus Miracle.

Hope this answer helped! If you have any questions or suggestions, feel free to edit my question or leave a comment!

Answer (score -3):

You can copy main levels, but to do so you either hack the game or find out the passcode of an online copy of the level.

Comment: Please don't use run off sentences. the reason why the minimum character limit is there is to tell you when your answer is lacking as good answers aren't that short

Comment: @Memor-X That's some backwards logic, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @user1337 how is it backwards logic? any twit can say "you hack the game" as an answer to any question here. this answer could easily have easily met the minimum character limit by explaining how to hack the game or providing an example passcode of another level to shows validity to the method.

Comment: @Memor-X I was referring to you saying "Good answers aren't that short", i.e. "_An answer that is short can not be of good quality_". There are plenty of examples on the site of good short answers and bad long answers. Ti's all m8.